# Android, why AdView does not display anything?

Tags: android, intellij-idea, admob, google-play-services, adview

Based on what [documentation says](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/fundamentals#play-xml), I added AdView to my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewPager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            ads:adUnitId="@string/api_key_admob"
            ads:adSize="BANNER"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

and This is the method that I've added into my activity:

```
private void displayAdmob() {
        AdView adView = (AdView)this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);
    }
```

and I've added these lines of code into the manifest file:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="mobilesoft.asia.malaysia_directory"
          android:versionCode="10"
          android:versionName="2.0">

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="15"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

    <application
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:theme = "@style/Theme.Example">

        <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
                android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
        <activity
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>

...

    </application>
</manifest>
```

When I run the application AdView does not display. I expect to see it below my view pager but there is no AdView. I'm suspicious to `ads:adUnitId="MY_AD_UNIT_ID"`. There is no AD_UNIT_ID in AdMob page when I created my Android App. I'm using "Publisher ID" which is provided by AdMob and assign it to `ads:adUnitId="Publisher_ID"` instead. Do you think that's my problem?

Second thing, I'm not using AdMob SDK. I've added "`google_play_services_lib`" into my project and using this library instead of AdMob SDK.

Any suggestion would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

shit, My XML design had problem.

I changed design of view pager as following code and AdView works properly at the bottom of screen:

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewPager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
```